# how to pass values from main to modal page and to servlet?

Tags: jsp, modal-dialog

I have a jsp(page1.jsp) which contains one text box and button. On click of this button I'm opening a modal window(page2.jsp). Even this contains one text box and button. On click of this button it takes the control to servlet.

Now I want the value of text box in page1 and page2. I'm able to retrieve the page2 values in servlet but not page1.

Please guide me how to do it?

Comment: Could you show us some code?  What did you try already? What are the errors you get?

Comment: Can you post your code?